# Manual IP configuration on RHEL 7 KVM guest installation

Tags: system-installation, virtual-machine, kvm

I have KVM set up on a RHEL 7 server with the installation media for guests being served via FTP. Whenever I kick off a new VM installation via Virtual Machine Manager (I'm doing graphical installation right now) I find that I cannot manually configure the IP. The `Save` button is greyed out.

Is this due to it being a KVM installation? Does RHEL 7 not allow manual IP configuration during the install? Is it something else?